# Ratio of electrical input to mechanical input in a synchronous generator

Tags: generator, synchronous-motor

In a synchronous generator we want to convert mechanical to electrical power but the thing that confuses me is that we also use electrical input as dc current which goes through rotor windings to
make our rotor magnetic field. I couldn’t find a ratio of electrical input power to mechanical input power. Is this small? And can we make this electrical input small and make mechanical bigger?
So overall we have converted more mechanical to electrical?

Comment: Field windings usually require a small portion of the total power output. You could if you wished use the output electrical power to operate the field windings once the generator is operating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent one using a generator with permenant magnets instead of field coils.  In fact many domestic scale wind turbines use magnets.

It is just that in larger setups, field coils are more practical, despite the reduction in efficiency for the resistive losses in those windings (which is small compared to the generated power) .

Answer (score 3):

The DC input is 'small'. It is unrelated to the output. It is related to the quality of mechanical construction, particularly the size of the air-gap (smaller is better).

In an ideal generator with superconducting rotor windings, the current would be zero.

In a well-constructed generator, the excitation power should be only a few percent at most of the rated output power.

Comment: I think with superconducting field windings the current in the windings would be finite/large, but the resistive losses (so ongoing power requirement) would be zero.